# Use an admin html template with react-boilerplate

Tags: symfony, bower, react-boilerplate

I already have a HTML Admin template that use bower components (datepickers, sliders, switchers, dropdowns, charts, etc, etc). This template has a layout that I want to use in my app.

I'm trying to figure of could I use this template AND react-boilertplate.

I already use this template with React and Symfony, with no problems, works very ok. The structure is something like this:

```
- Main Symfony App folder
    - Some Symfony folder
    - Some Symfony folder
    - the SRC Symfony folder where I Have all the bundles
        - UserBundle: here I have the React componentes
    - the Web Symfony folder: this is the public content
        - here I have assets, bower components, etc.
```

But now my goal is to move out all the React part and put them in the Web folder, and here I'll have the react-boilerplate working.

But I don't know where to start. Could anyone give a hint on how to use an already made html template with tons of bower componentes, but powered with react-boilerplate?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

create a separate web folder, that would be independent from your symfony project, like client/template for example, and with the help of a module bundler extract the compressed/minimized files into the web folder.
it will also help you migrate to symfony 4 easily 
http://fabien.potencier.org/symfony4-directory-structure.html